# How do i solve a MissingSpecError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When running `rails new test-app` i am running into this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    22: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    21: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    20: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    19: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:295:in `activate_bin_path'
    18: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:295:in `synchronize'
    17: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    16: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1373:in `activate'
    15: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `activate_dependencies'
    14: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `each'
    13: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    12: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1373:in `activate'
    11: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `activate_dependencies'
    10: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `each'
     9: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     8: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1373:in `activate'
     7: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `activate_dependencies'
     6: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `each'
     5: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1405:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     4: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1373:in `activate'
     3: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `activate_dependencies'
     2: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1391:in `each'
     1: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1402:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.5.9) among 96 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0:/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

i tried to rebuild the xcode utilities. unfortunately this did not work. googling gave me many results but not the right one. what can i do?

EDIT: as Tom Lord correctly stated did `gem install nokogiri` the trick. I thought by installing the utilities this issue would not occur. as well as the fact, that i am developing for several years on this machine now and never had to manually install a gem. anyway it works now, so this is closed

Comment: The error says that `nokogiri` is not installed.... When you installed `rails`, did this show an error saying the `nokogiri` failed to install?? What happens if you run `gem install nokogiri`, now? If that shows an error, what is it?

Comment: weird thing is, that the machine i am running and developing my apps on is in use for years and i never had the problem. doesnt `gem install nokogiri` require to have a gemfile? I only run in this error when initializing a fresh rails application

Comment: "doesnt gem install nokogiri require to have a gemfile?" -- **No.** A `Gemfile` lists dependencies for a specific application, but it is still totally valid to install gems individually, independent of any application. A ruby application doesn't even *need* a `Gemfile`; it's just become extremely common practice to provide one.

Comment: @TomLord thank you for your explaination tom. i tried and everything works fine now. i misunderstood the concept of gems entirely for all the years.

Answer (score 0):

`gem install nokogiri` as this dependency is missing.